How do AWS ECR Lifecycle policies interact with multiplatform images
Specifically, if i have a policy that says to delete images without tags, and i push a multiplatform image - the "Image Index" is tagged, but the "Image" artifact is not tagged. will it get cleaned up by the policy, even though it would not have been had it not been a multiplatform image?

As far as I can tell from testing, the lifecycle policy would mark the image as to delete, but then fails to delete it because it's being referenced in a manifest.
